# Get the Source of an image and open in a new window when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have an series of images in a table and I need to open them in new window/tab using JavaScript or Jquery when we click on the image.
Since these images might change over time, I thought it would be a good idea to get the src attribute of these images and open them in new window using that src attribute automatically. that way we can reduce some maintenance for the code.

Since I am a newbie for JavaScript. I need help in figuring out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$("table tr td img").click(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    window.open(
        '/' + src, //change this to your relative path + src
        '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
    );
});
```

Comment: Hi, I planned to include the images in <a> tag so can I replace table tr td with 'a' tag so that img which is a child of this is clicked would do the needful?

Comment: Here is html I am using..the JQuery is not firing..:(

Comment: <head>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $("a img").click(function () {
         alert("In JQuery Function after click");
         var src = $(this).attr("src");
         alert(src);
         window.open(
        '/' + src, //change this to your relative path + src
        '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
    );
     });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#"> <img  alt="klsdls" id="Img7" src="images/img2"   title="Click to see an enlarged Image" height="100px" width="50px"/></a>

Answer (score 1):

Use `target="_blank"` for your anchor tag

```
<a href="your-image-path" target="_blank"><img src="your-image-path"/></a>
```

Comment: Yeah.. This is the simplest option.. but since everytime the image changes, we need to update at two places. one for image src and one for 'a' Tag. So, we need a way to get the Image Id and it opens automatically in a new window when clicked.

Comment: Use `<c:url var="imageUrl" value="your-image-source" /> <a href="${imageUrl}" target="_blank"><img src="${imageUrl}"/></a>` This will surely reduce your url repeatition.

Comment: And dont forget to add taglib in the begining of your page: `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`